# Adding textfeilds on top of drawing veiw image XCode SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Essentially I would like to add text fields on top of my image.
Currently, my `viewDidLoad()` is currently set up as such.

-Image Background (UIImage)

--Drawing Canvas

I would like it to be set up as such so that it is not possible to draw over the text fields, as I realize it is possible to add text over the image itself

-Image Background (UIImage)

---Drawing Canvas

-----TextFeild Struct

I would assume I need to use `UITextField` but I keep on getting this error in my simulation.

> (Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
> Optional value)

In addition to this error, I'm unable to edit the scaling of my image background. I tried everything turning the `imageView` to content mode, and modifying the image before adding the view (scaleAspectFit/scaleAspectFill), resizing the view  the only thing that seemed to work was changing the resolution of the source image.

[I would like to add text fields up top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roTBl.png)

```swift
class DrawingCanvasViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    
    lazy var canvas: PKCanvasView = {
        let view = PKCanvasView()
        view.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        view.minimumZoomScale = 1
        view.maximumZoomScale = 1
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return view
    }()
        
    
    lazy var toolPicker: PKToolPicker = {
        let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
        toolPicker.addObserver(self)
        return toolPicker
    }()
    
    var drawingData = Data()
    var drawingChanged: (Data) -> Void = {_ in}
    
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(canvas)
        canvas.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let iTest=UIImage(named: "Test2")
            
        let imageView=UIImageView(image: iTest)

//This is what I have used for trying to resize my background image, although none of it seems to ever work        
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)


//The fatal error it gives me is from these two lines below    
    
//        view.addSubview(nameTextField)
//        view.bringSubviewToFront(nameTextField)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                        canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                                        canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                                        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                                        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)])
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
        canvas.delegate = self
        canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
        if let drawing = try? PKDrawing(data: drawingData){
            canvas.drawing = drawing
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Xcode, I did follow a tutorial to add the pencil kit UI although am currently unable to refind it, and I figured out how to add the background image from looking at apple documentation, Hence I may have simply missed an easier/better way to code my app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. You should focus on a single issue at a time. So -- *"I would assume I need to use UITextFeild but I keep on getting this error in my simulation. (Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value)"* -- you didn't show us **where** you are getting that error? Pretty tough to help you with any of your code if it doesn't even run because of that error.

Answer (score 0):

what I'm seeing from your code is: that you added UITextField in your Xib/Storyboard file. Therefore you can remove the reference of UITextField in the Xib/Storyboard file with the controller and introduce UITextField programmatically. My solution below will only address the fatal error from the 2 lines:

> view.addSubview(nameTextField)
> view.bringSubviewToFront(nameTextField)

Then let me know other issues when you get this one working first. Please adjust the contrainst of nameTextField to have it visible.

```
class DrawingCanvasViewController: UIViewController {

    // initialise text field 
    lazy var nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
        // Please setup delegate by yourself 
        return textField  
    }()
    
    lazy var canvas: PKCanvasView = {
        let view = PKCanvasView()
        view.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        view.minimumZoomScale = 1
        view.maximumZoomScale = 1
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return view
    }()
        
    
    lazy var toolPicker: PKToolPicker = {
        let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
        toolPicker.addObserver(self)
        return toolPicker
    }()
    
    var drawingData = Data()
    var drawingChanged: (Data) -> Void = {_ in}
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(canvas)
        canvas.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let iTest=UIImage(named: "Test2")
            
        let imageView=UIImageView(image: iTest)

        //This is what I have used for trying to resize my background image, 
        // although none of it seems to ever work        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)  

        // since you already created the nameTextField as a lazy variable
       // then you can add it here     
        view.addSubview(nameTextField)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(nameTextField)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                        canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                                        canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                                        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                                        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)])
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
        canvas.delegate = self
        canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
        if let drawing = try? PKDrawing(data: drawingData){
            canvas.drawing = drawing
        }
    }
}
```